# Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy error in Automation runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

I'm following [this guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/24/create-backups-of-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure-by-using-powershell.aspx) to automate backups of Linux VMs in Azure Automation. Everything goes well in testing on initial run, but the second and all subsequent tests return the following error:

```
11/26/2014 11:03:45 AM, Error: Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy : One or more errors occurred.
At LinuxVMBackup:40 char:40
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
AggregateException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.StartAzureStorageBlobCopy
```

Here is the runbook:

```
workflow LinuxVMBackup
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [PSCredential]
        $Cred,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $subName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $serviceName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $vmName
    )

    # Login and get VM
    $null = Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
    $null = Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName
    $vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName

    # Stop VM 
    $vm | Stop-AzureVM -StayProvisioned

    # Get OS and Data Disks
    $vmOSDisk = Get-AzureOSDisk -VM (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName)
    $vmDataDisks = Get-AzureDataDisk -VM (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName)

    # Get and set storage name
    $StorageAccountName = $vmOSDisk.MediaLink.Host.Split('.')[0]
    Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $StorageAccountName -SubscriptionName $subName

    $backupContainerName = "backups"
    if (!(Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $backupContainerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
      New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $backupContainerName -Permission Off
    }

    # Snapshot OS Disk
    $vmOSBlobName = $vmOSDisk.MediaLink.Segments[-1]
    $vmOSContainerName = $vmOSDisk.MediaLink.Segments[-2].Split('/')[0]
   #Error on this line
        Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer $vmOSContainerName -SrcBlob $vmOSBlobName -DestContainer $backupContainerName 
   #Error on this line
    Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $backupContainerName -Blob $vmOSBlobName -WaitForComplete

    #Snapshot Data Disks
    ForEach ($vmDataDisk in $vmDataDisks) {
      $vmDataBlobName = $vmDataDisk.MediaLink.Segments[-1]
      $vmDataContainerName = $vmDataDisk.MediaLink.Segments[-2].Split('/')[0]

      Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer $vmDataContainerName -SrcBlob $vmDataBlobName -DestContainer $backupContainerName -Force
      Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $backupContainerName -Blob $vmDataBlobName -WaitForComplete
    }

    #Get blobs in storage and output
    $insertedBlobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $backupContainerName
    Write-Output $insertedBlobs
    $vm | Start-AzureVM

}
```

I couldn't find anything online, save an answer on Microsoft forums for a similar error stating that the VM needs to be stopped, so I thought maybe the VM is not fully stopped when Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy is initiated. I tried testing with a stopped VM and still got the error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the error only happens after the first successful copy, what is probably happening is the Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy cmdlet is trying to request user confirmation for the operation, since it would overwrite existing data. Since Azure Automation runs runbooks in a non-interactive session, user confirmation cannot be asked, so the command is failing.

Adding -Force should "force" user confirmation for the cmdlet and fix the issue. You have this parameter on the second instance of Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy, but not the first.

PS - You should put this runbook in our [runbook gallery](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/07/introducing-the-azure-automation-runbook-gallery/) so others can take advantage of it!

Comment: Hello Joe, thank you for the answer. I used -Force and it works. It was indeed trying to overwrite one blob snapshot, since I was not using -DestBlob to set a new name. Thanks again!